# Java error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am making a simple program that will take one word with "*" in the middle of the word ex: "Some*ing" and will take another string to replace it with the "*" in the first word. Like "th" -> output "Something".

Sample Run 1:

Enter the first String:

D*g

Enter the replacement String:

in

Ding

Simple enough. I made this program in IDEA (running Java 8) and it works alright (though I still need to add some minor stuff). 
But in CodeRunner I have some problems. It says "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1". There is some mistake in my code and I have no idea where it is. 
My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first String:");
        //The inital String
        String first = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the replacement String:");
        // SubString
        String subs = scan.nextLine();

        if (!(first.contains("!") || first.contains("@") || first.contains("#") || first.contains("$") || first.contains("%") || first.contains("^") || first.contains("&") || first.contains("(") || first.contains(")") || first.contains("+") || first.contains("-") || first.contains("_") || first.contains("~") || first.contains("`") || first.contains("\\") || first.contains("[") || first.contains("]") || first.contains("{") || first.contains("}") || first.contains(":") || first.contains(";") || first.contains("'") || first.contains("\"") || first.contains("/") || first.contains("?") || first.contains(".") || first.contains(">") || first.contains(",") || first.contains("<"))) {

            if (first.contains("*") ) {
                String parts[] = first.split("\\*");

                String part1 = parts[0];
                String part2 = parts[1];
                String newString = part1 + subs + part2;
                System.out.println(newString);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: no *");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect characters");
        }
    }
}
```

The CodeRunner gives me that

```
Runtime Error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Main.main(Main.java:298)
    at Ideone.assertRegex(Main.java:125)
    at Ideone.test(Main.java:61)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:28)
```

Though code works at my IDE and we assume that it is possible to make so the code will work at the codeRunner

Thank you

Comment: Read the exception. Debug based on what it is telling you. On line 298 of Main.java you are accessing `something[1]` when it doesn't exist.

Comment: Looks like `String parts[] = first.split("\\*");` is not doing what you expect it to do. It will split on the characters `\ ` and `*` . No regex action going on there. Check out the `File` class and see if it offers you some useful methods (hint: it does). Also, screen your code for inappropriate language.

Comment: Go through your  `loop`s and learn how they work in runtime

Comment: John3136 there is no line 298. My class is only has about 80 lines.

Comment: RESOLVED ! Thank's everybody

Answer (score 0):

Note: StringBuilder used only for demo

```
if (YOURSTRING.contains("*")) {
   StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
   String parts[] = YOURSTRING.split("\\*");
   for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
       builder.append(parts[i]);
   }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
} else {
  System.out.println("Error: no *");
}
```

use for loop instead of getting value statically from array
because if spit will done 1 time of non then this line 
`String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];` return ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because there is not a second element int array to get it, understood?

Comment: the getText() method... It doesn't work. I am pretty new at Java, so I might ask some lamer's questions, but oh well

Comment: Got it. But how to embed the subWord between the two parts? Just do      System.out.println(parts[0] + subs + parts[1]);? Or that is going to case the same problem ?

Comment: I did notice the logic, but it's just I am really new to Java, so I though that these were real methods

Comment: User enters "Ame*ca" then he enters "ri" . The output is "America". And it's really my school assignment

Comment: @user3687547 [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) should be all you need.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter thank you man! You've saved my butt from an F! I am done with thins assignment by using s.replace(); I even fit in just 20 lines!Thank you man!  Thank's everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Thank's everybody who was helping me! I've learned about 10 new methods while solving this assignment until I found the resolution. That was a helpful experience. This assignment is done, I got an A for it (100%)!  Thank you guys!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AsmntFive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first String:");

        String first = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the replacement String:");

        String subs = scan.nextLine();

        if (!(first.contains("!") || first.contains("@") || first.contains("#") || first.contains("$") || first.contains("%") || first.contains("^") || first.contains("&") || first.contains("(") || first.contains(")") || first.contains("+") || first.contains("-") || first.contains("_") || first.contains("~") || first.contains("`") || first.contains("\\") || first.contains("[") || first.contains("]") || first.contains("{") || first.contains("}") || first.contains(":") || first.contains(";") || first.contains("'") || first.contains("\"") || first.contains("/") || first.contains("?") || first.contains(".") || first.contains(">") || first.contains(",") || first.contains("<"))) {

            if (first.contains("*")) {
                System.out.println(first.replace("*", subs));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: no *");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect characters");

        }
    }
}
```